# Coloring of a table with red or green rows and columns

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, coloring

> In a 10×10 table, half of the cells are red and half are green. Let's
> call a row or a column good if all cells in it are the same color.
> What is the maximal total number of good rows and columns in such a
> table?

The simple and obvious answer is 10. I've been trying to search for different intersections of the same color, yet 10 is still the biggest number. Can there be 11, for instance?

Comment: 10 rows + 10 columns, if the grid is one-color. It is what you´re thinking of, when writing 10?

Comment: By symmetry, we may assume there is at least one good red column.  There can then be no good green rows.  If there is at least one green column, then there can be no good red rows, in which case the max is obviously $10$.  So you are down to the case in which there are only good red rows and red columns.

Comment: @user376343 Likely 5 good red columns and 5 good green columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are at least 11 good rows and columns. there must be at least 1 good row and at least 1 good column. this row and column must have the same color because they intersect. WLOG say they are red. the red row precludes green columns and the red column precludes green rows, so there cannot be any green rows or columns. suppose there are $m$ red rows and $n$ red columns.
$$10m+10n-mn\leq 50$$
$$(10-m)(10-n)\geq 50$$
$$\frac{(10-m)+(10-n)}{2}\geq \sqrt{(10-m)(10-n)}\geq 5\sqrt2$$
$$m+n\leq 20-10\sqrt2<6$$
contradiction. so there are at most 10 good rows and columns. the construction is 5 green, 5 red, all parallel to one another.